# error: The argument type 'String' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'Uri'

Tags: dart

```
import 'dart:convert';

import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;



class RequestAssistants
{
  static Future<dynamic> getRequest(String url)  async
  {
    http.Response response = await http.get(url);

    try
    {
      if(response.statusCode == 200)
      {
        String jSonData = response.body;
        var decodeData = jsonDecode(jSonData);
        return decodeData;
      }
      else
      {
        return "failed";
      }

    }
    catch(exp)
    {
      return "failed";

    }
  }

}
```

> error: The argument type 'String' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'Uri'. (argument_type_not_assignable at [user_app] lib/Assistants/requestAssistants.dart:13)

Comment: Can anyone please help me solving this error? Thank You.

Comment: `http.get(url);` needs a Uri type. You are providing it the string you got from `getRequest(String url)`. A String is not a Uri See https://pub.dev/documentation/http/latest/http/get.html and https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.10.5/dart-core/Uri/Uri.http.html

Comment: Solution: http.Response response = await http.get(Uri.parse(url));